# What GSM of paper should I use for reprinting cards to use in deck sleeves

Tags: card-sleeves, judge-dredd

**UPDATE:** Not knowing how the forum worked, I asked a question and, in retrospect, I should have provided more detail on work I had already done / was doing when it occurred to me to ask the question!  With very kind intention, my post was edited to ask what people assumed would be easier.  However, I've already spent ages scanning the old card fronts and purchased the card sleeves for how I'm resizing the cards, it really wouldn't be easier (or definitely not cheaper) to do anything other than to press ahead at this stage.

---

An old favourite game (the Judge Dredd Board Game if anyone remembers or cares) has gotten to the stage when all of us can recognise half the cards from the back by the staining and marks on the cards.  This is the second time I've bought the game as it happened before as well.

I had considered re-buying again and getting deck sleeves but (perhaps erroneously considering answers given) I didn't believe that I could get the right size of cards.  So I have scanned all the different sets of cards (this afternoon since posting), redesigned the card backs (less solid black) and have resized the cards slightly to perfectly fit the card sleeves that I have already ordered.

I only really want to know if this world work with a lightweight card (say 150GSM) or whether something like 270GSM would work better.

Comment: If you own some cards which fit into common sleeves, it would be a cost-effective solution to put those cards into sleeves as a stabilizer and place a piece of paper in front of it, indicating which Judge Dredd Board Game card it is supposed to represent. It can even be a xerox'd version of the original.

Comment: @Thunderforge I did a quick look over at BGG and it looks like the cards for this game aren't a standard size, so there currently aren't sleeves that fit them well. My understanding of this question is they are looking for a way to print the cards so that they are a standard size so they can get sleeves that will work for them.

Comment: @Thunderforge https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1084950/sleeving-cards

Comment: Looking at FFG's offerings the Mini European look the closest, but the discussion I linked to says they are too wide

Comment: Thanks Thunderforge - as I didn't think the right size existed for either (and it costs a good £50) I pressed on with the other.  I recognise that you're almost certainly right and it is a complex way I've chosen but sometimes it's nice to do things properly for yourself.  It'll really feel like my game now.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question; like I said, I encouraged you to edit your question if I misunderstood what it was. I've deleted my answer since it's no longer relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Paper is a bit more complex than just the GSM as you can get different thickness, stiffness and other properties.

The general "best" GSM for cards will be around 300GSM, but you'll want to feel the sheet of paper first for thickness and stiffness as well. It'll be no good to have a lovely printed card that flops about in your hand or flexes too much to shuffle easily.

[This thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1070103/paper-weight-playing-cards) on BGG suggests using paper stock that's designed for business card usage as it's widely available.

[This custom card printer](http://www.makeplayingcards.com/printed-card-types.aspx) uses 300, 310 or 270GSM for their playing cards depending on paper type and required quality.

You will find a lot of home printers won't be able to print on high GSM paper - check your specifications for your printer if you want to print at home.

If you're getting it professionally printed at a print shop, ask for some paper samples, and have a test page to print on each paper so you can see the differences.

I had some success in printing at home some card dividers on 180GSM matte photo paper and laminating the entire page in high quality 125 micron before cutting out using a paper guillotine. This produced a very stiff card that was slightly glossy, despite the stock being not that stiff to begin with. As you're planning on sleeving, I'd go the higher GSM paper straight away and skip laminating.